# Change the timezone (TZ environment variable) for a running irssi session?

Tags: environment-variables, irssi, time-zone

When travelling to other timezones, I set `TZ=/usr/share/zoneinfo/current_timezone` on remote shells where I log on to, including the shell in which I run irssi inside tmux.  Can I change the `TZ` for a running `irssi` session, or otherwise inform `irssi` of an updated timezone, without restarting `irssi`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/script exec $ENV{'TZ'}='Europe/Vatican'
```